# Conda Package Metadata Not Being Pushed

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda, conda, setuptools

I have a Python library I created that I have as a Conda package. Although I made sure to include all the metadata fields, when the package is installed on the system none of the details are available, i.e. description, home, etc.

The package install is successful, however, I would like for the user to see the metadata. I have tried inputting simple dummy values as well with no luck. The only values that seem to come across are the name (lafpy) and version (0.2.6). Below is the code from both my setup.py and meta.yaml files.

```py
# Setup.py
import setuptools, os

def read(fname):
    return open(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), fname)).read()

setuptools.setup(
    name='lafpy',
    version='0.2.6',
    description='Lands and Forestry Python Library',
    url='https://bitbucket.org/nsdnrforestry/lafpy.git',
    author='René Ténière',
    author_email='test@novascotia.ca',
    #long_description='Test',
    long_description=read('README.md'),
    long_description_content_type="text/markdown",
    license='Nova Scotia Department of Lands and Forestry',
    keywords='lafpy lands forestry arcpy arcgis pro python',
    packages=setuptools.find_packages(),
    python_requires='>=3.4,<3.7',
    install_requires=['pyodbc'],
    data_files=[('lafpy_support', ['lafpy_support/source.gpx'])],
    platforms=['win64', 'win32'],
    zip_safe=True)
```

```
# meta.yaml

{% set data = load_setup_py_data() %}

package:
    name: lafpy
    # name: {{ data['name'] }}
    version: {{ data['version'] }}
source:
    git_url: https://bitbucket.org/nsdnrforestry/lafpy.git
build:
    skip: True  # [py<34]
    number: 0
    script: pip install .
    # script: python setup.py sdist install --single-version-externally-managed --record=record.txt
    # preserve_egg_dir: True
requirements:
    host:
        - python 3.6.6
        - setuptools 39.2.0 py36_0
    run:
        - python >=3.6,<3.7
        # dependencies are defined in setup.py
        {% for dep in data['install_requires'] %}
        - {{ dep.lower() }}
        {% endfor %}
about:
    home: https://bitbucket.org/nsdnrforestry/lafpy
    license: {{ data['license'] }}
    # license: 'test_license'
    license_file: LICENSE.txt
    description: {{ data['description'] }}
    # description: 'test_desc'
    summary: {{ data['long_description'] }}
    # summary: 'Lands and Forestry Python Library'
    dev_url: {{ data['url'] }}
    # dev_url: https://bitbucket.org/nsdnrforestry/lafpy
    doc_source_url: https://bitbucket.org/nsdnrforestry/lafpy/README.md
```

I have checked Anaconda Navigator and no metadata is populated. 
[Anaconda Navigator - Image of lafpy with no description.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WGz7M.png)
I have looked at the dist-info folder, and the metadata is filled in properly in the METADATA and License.txt files. What am I doing wrong? Where does Anaconda Navigator pull the metadata from for the description?